# Remove shape from path in core graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-graphics, drawrect

I originally had this code, to create a 'bottom highlight' on buttons:

```
CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5]CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

This would draw the highlight in the same space as the button, but 1 pixel lower, and this worked fine, as the buttons weren't transparent. I now have some transparent ones, however, so I need to remove the area behind the button from the drawing area.

I've tried using `EOClip` to do this, but wasn't able to figure out which combination to use. The button's path is called `buttonPath`, the highlight path is the same but 1 pixel lower, and called `highlightPath`. How could i stop it from drawing inside `buttonPath`, while drawing to highlightPath?

EDIT:

Ok, so both this and switching lines 2 and 3 result in the whole shape being colored, and an error of `clip: empty path.`:

```
CGContextEOClip(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, buttonPath);
CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

Comment: What with `EOClip` did you try?

Comment: Yes, but EO stands for even-odd = path on top of path is even and won't be filed.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist So how could I use it with my above code to make it draw to `highlightPath`, minus `buttonPath`?

Comment: Add both paths and see what happens ;)

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Edited with result.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30679/discussion-between-david-ronnqvist-and-andrew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As concluded from the chat, you can add both paths and fill with an even-odd fill mode to get the desired result

```
CGContextAddPath(context, buttonPath); 
CGContextAddPath(context, highlightPath); 
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.5] CGColor]);
CGContextEOFillPath(context);
```